# GDB error Dwarf Error: bad offset (0x40f000) in compilation unit header (offset 0x0 + 6)

Tags: c, gcc, gdb, cygwin

I tried to compile a simple Hello World program in C, and debug it in GDB (just to make sure my setup works). If I try to run the program normally it works, but whenever I try to open it using GDB I get the following error:

`Dwarf Error: bad offset (0x40f000) in compilation unit header (offset 0x0 + 6) [in module /cygdrive/c/Users/Guy/tests/main.exe]`

Here is my Makefile:

```
CC = gcc
NASM = nasm
FLAGS = -ggdb -Wall -m64
ASMFLAGS = -f elf64 -g -Wall


all: main

%.o: %.c
      $(CC) $(FLAGS) $< -c

%.o : %.asm
      $(NASM) $(ASMFLAGS) $< -o $@

main : main.c
      $(CC) $(FLAGS) -o $@ $^


clean:
      rm *.o

// I intend to add files written in nasm in the future, but currently my only file is main.c
```

And here is my C program (main.c):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char* str = "Hello World!";
    printf("%s", str);
    return 0;
}
```

To compile the program I use gcc, which I download and run through cygwin.

I run GDB through cygwin as well.

To solve the problem I tried changing the flags to include different combinations of -g, -Wall, -ggdb, -Fdwarf.

I also tried recompiling the program with different versions of gcc and gdb.

But at last each and every one of my attempts failed, and in all of them I got the same error.

To make sure there is no problem with my dwarf information I used dwarfdump. The output is quite long and I don't know whether it is proper or not, but if someone wants to take a look at it please ask and I'll upload it.

Comment: What does `uname -a` output in *Cygwin* terminal?

Comment: CYGWIN_NT-10.0-19045 GuyComputer 3.4.5-1.x86_64 2023-01-19 19:09 UTC x86_64 Cygwin

Comment: Does the program run stand-alone? Does the `gdb` work with other programs?

Comment: Yes the program runs if I just run it through the terminal without GDB.

Comment: And GDB works fine if I compile the same program with the gcc version of MinGW.

Comment: Could be that you are running MinGW version of gdb ? Instead of Cygwin's one. Make sure that your `gdb` is matching the toolchain used to compile.

Comment: Yep, that doe's the trick. Thanks!

Comment: remove the `-f elf64` . Cygwin is NOT Linux, it uses the same standard as Windows